# changeset error - salesforce selected flow must have an active version

Tags: change-set

Our changeset contains flows, page layouts, user profiles, community, apex, etc. It is a very bulky changeset. How do you solve this error?[image]

Comment: Are those flows added to the `enabled flow access` on those profiles? Are you able to provide any info on what those flows/profiles look like in your source org?

Comment: do you have login flows that the profile references that might not be activated?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves actually the `enabled flow access` list is empty for both profiles. The thing is that I have no idea about which flow Salesforce is complaining about

Comment: @cropredy besides `enable flow access` (which is empty) in the profile page. Where can I see flows referenced by these two profiles?

Comment: look at the XML for the Profile in your source org and go through the entries in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm that reference flows

Answer (score 1):

@oabarca Based on the error, when your change-set is being deployed it looks like your profile has flow access and looking for an active version in both of your flows shown in your picture.

Please make sure you have atleast one active version for both the flows.

[image]

Also since you are moving profiles along with flows in your change-set, make sure you have given flow access in the below section of your profile.

[image]

Let me know if the above information helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found two solutions:

- If you're trying to deploy a new Login Flow and its assignment for a given Profile, you will get this error. Remove the profile assignment, deploy the Login Flow, then re-assign it in the target org
- If you're using Flow Assignments on Profile ("Profile" >> "Flow Access"), you need to make sure the  tag on the Profile matches with any FlowDefinition metadata and any Flow metadata. For example, if you have a  that gives the Profile access to a Flow, make sure the Flow has Active and the FlowDefinition has a matching  or is not included in the deployment.
  Refs:

Gearset: https://gearset.com/blog/what-is-the-salesforce-metadata-flowaccesses/